# Dealing with DataResponse<Any> in Xcode 8 (Swift)

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am a newbie to iOS and I am using alamofire. When i call the API the result is successfully getting printed to console as shown

[image: here]

What I want is, to only extract the message from this response and present it to user. How to do it? 
I have searched for this but I found content related to converting string to JSON object or JSON object to JSON string. But my response is of type `DataResponse<Any>` and I don't know exactly how to deal with it.

P.s I am using Xcode 8, Swift 3.

Comment: Hi @kinza use can use https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
if let object = response.result.value as? [String:Any], let message = object["message"] as? String {
    print(message) // "User has been successfully registrered"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As **Rashwan L** Answer is perfect !!

Still I am suggesting A better way to do it using **ObjectMapper**

It is very easy to access each property easily

First You need to Download   **SwiftyJSONAccelerator** application in your system which let you convert your **JSON** Response to **Class** or **struct** whatever you need.

From

https://github.com/insanoid/SwiftyJSONAccelerator

And Create **Class** for your JSON, And Select **ObjectMapper** if you are not using **SwiftyJosn** from drop down Where there are three options.

Drag and drop all generated class file to your XCode make sure you  select Copy Item if needed Check box Selected

**How to use ?**

```
       import ObjectMapper


        WebServices().getMyWSResponse(success: { (response) in
            guard let res = response as? [String:Any], let obect = Mapper<MYGeneratedModelClass>().map(JSON: res) else {
                return
            }

            //Here you get  obect  , You can access object.message

        }, error: { (error) in

        })
    }
```

Note:  `WebServices().getMyWSResponse` is My Class to call ws you don't need to worry about that

Hope it is helpful to you